# Need Help Uninstalling Stencyl

Tags: haxe, openfl, stencyl

When I try to install openFL with Haxe I get this error:

```
C:\Users\Dude>haxelib install openfl
You already have openfl version 3.3.0 installed
[file_contents,C:\Program Files (x86)\Stencyl\plaf\haxe\lib/openfl/.current]
```

I have uninstalled Stencyl from program files (Win8.1_64bit) and ran CCleaner to make sure I was wiped out. Also I checked system and user environmental variables but didn't found Stencyl anywhere.

Then I have reinstalled Haxe over again, but for some reason I keep getting the same error.
After the fresh installation, I have checked the installation location of Haxe by using the `>haxelib config` command but still I get this weird output

```
C:\Users\Dude>haxelib config
C:\Program Files (x86)\Stencyl\plaf\haxe\lib/
```

Currently haxe is installed at `C:\HaxeToolkit` on my machine

Answer (score 0):

Well I just entered the Stencyl keyword in the windows search bar and saw this file: **.hxcpp_config.xml**. This file and another one called **.haxelib** was located in my user Home folder.

### The problem was fixed after deleting both of this files.

Also I found were stencyl was hiding (ಠ_ಠ ). The file **.hxcpp_config.xml** directs to the AppData folder in the user directory (C:\Users\Dude\AppData\Roaming\Stencyl)